# Why is this function returning an empty list?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my code, this function retrieves a list of flashcards from a room database. I know that an empty list can returned if there are no flashcards that match the requirements passed into the function. However we are setting an initial value, so shouldn't that initial value be returned instead of an empty list? Any help would be appreciated.

Function that retrieves flashcards:

```
fun getFlaggedFlashcardsFilteredByTopic(topic: String): StateFlow<List<Flashcard>> {
        return flashcardsRepository.getFlaggedFlashcardsStreamFilteredByTopic(topic = topic)
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(timeoutMillis),
                initialValue = listOf(Flashcard())
            )
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> shouldn't that initial value be returned instead of an empty list?

No, it shouldn't. Initial value is not some kind of a default value in the case the result is empty. Initial value is used until a real value is fetched from the database and if there are no flashcards then it is expected to get an empty list.